# How do I make my StackPanel slide to the side when I click a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

So I have a project with my own UserControl that is build around a `ListBox` and I want to make it to where when I click a Item in the `ListBox`,
I want my `StackPanel` to slide to the right.
And when I click another item, the `StackPanel` should slide back to where it started from and then slide out again.

This can be done using `RadioButtons` but I am not sure if you can mix those in any way, because with `RadioButtons` you can keep track of wether a item is selected by using a bool because the `RadioButton` has the `isChecked` property.
Making it to where.. If the `RadioButton` is Checked it turns to `true` and then the `Animation` triggers on `True` and when you click a new `RadioButton` it turns to `false` because the one you had selected is not selected anymore. But then `true` again when you click a new one.
And the `false` would obviously trigger the slide in animation.

So I guess I need to check if an item is selected in the ListBox so something like this maybe?

```
foreach(Item item in MyListBox.Items)        
    if(MyListBox.SelectedItems.Contains(item)
        MyObject.Value = true;
    else
        MyObject.Value = false;
```

But using XAML ofcourse databainding it.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <system:Double x:Key="SlideOffSet">50</system:Double>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SlideRight">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="0" To="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SlideLeft">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}" To="0"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="UserControl"/>

        <StackPanel Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Background="Gray">

            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=SelectedItem.IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideRight}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideLeft}" />
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>

            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

My UserControl

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
        <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                 x:Name="TheListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" Padding="0,0,8,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- Selected Item -->
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <!-- Image Item -->
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <!-- Main content-->
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!-- Item image -->
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" Padding="8">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
                                       Height="40"
                                       Width="40"/>
                            </Border>


                            <!-- Main Content -->
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" Padding="0,0,8,0">
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <!-- Main Content -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue=Title}"
                                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"/>

                                    <!-- Main Content -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username, FallbackValue=Username}"
                                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                    <!-- Website URl -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Password, FallbackValue=https://facebook.com}" Foreground="Gray"
                                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Border"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        BorderThickness="5,0,0,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </Trigger>


                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>

                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

EntryItemViewModel.cs

```
public class EntryItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _title;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

AllEntriesListViewModel.cs

```
public class AllEntriesListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<EntryItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EntryItemViewModel>();

        public EntryItemViewModel EntryItemViewModel { get; set; } = new EntryItemViewModel();

        public AllEntriesListViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World1" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World2" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World3" });
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I tried adding a Converter but it's still not reacting to me selecing a value

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((EntryItemViewModel)value != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=AllEntriesListViewModel.SelectedItem.IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource EntryModelConverter}}" Value="True">`

If I put a breakpoint on the property, it gets the selected EntryViewModel but the animation isnt reacting

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=SelectedItem.IsSelected}" Value="True">` is not working as your UserControl does not have a property name SelectedItem. It is for the ListBox inside the UserControl.

You need to create a property "SelectedItem" in your ViewModel of UserControl (AllEntriesListViewModel) and bind SelectedItem to that property, and then if you use DataContext.SelectedItem `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem.IsSelected}" Value="True">` it would be able to access the property.

Edit:

You would also need to create one more boolean property IsSelected in the AllEntriesListViewModel, and change that property based on the SelectedItem change.

```
    private EntryItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public EntryItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if(_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                IsSelected = !IsSelected;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
            }                
        }
    }
```

and bind the data trigger to DataContext.IsSelected.

Comment: I tried using `EntryItemViewModel` as the type but the panel wont move, using bool will make the control get a red line around it

Comment: SelectedItem would of type EntryItemViewModel, the reason why the panel is not moving as EntryItemViewModel does not have IsSelected. Do you want to slide left right the panel if any item is selected? If yes; use Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, write a converter to return true if the selected item is not null and false if null.

Comment: DataContext being what ever I set the DataContext to right? Just double checking

Comment: Also.. When it coems to the Converter, I don't follow your logic, It returns true if the value is not null, which is when there is an item selected, but it wont ever turn null again will it? I want it to slide back when I select a new item and then slide out again presenting the new data

Comment: I made a small edit to my question showing some code

Comment: Okay, if I understand it right you want to slide the stack panel to the left when the first item is selected, then slide right when selection is changed and again left for next?

Comment: I've edited my answer which should trigger the data trigger. Also, I am assuming DataContext of MyUserControl is set properly to an instance of AllEntriesListViewModel.

Comment: That's actually REALLY close! The only issue now is that.
When I select an item, it slides out.. Perfect! But when I select the next item, it slides back in.. I want it to slide back in and then directly slide back out again.

Comment: Okay, so for the above requirement - I think you should have the stack panel inside your ListBox's Item template for each item and not in the MainWindow and then binding directly to ListBox's selected item. But then, there would be one stack panel for each item.